# Calculate result of an election using the D'Hondt method

Tags: python, algorithm

I have learned about list comprehensions a week or so ago and understood that they can save a lot of screen space. Though, I have been told that this is bad practice only to use them, even if it brings tremendous benefits. Where is the line?

The version with no nested comprehensions is at least three times longer.

This function takes a dictionary like this and a number of seats in the council.

"Name": "Votes for 1st candidate","Votes for 2nd candidate",...

```
parties = {"020": [550,198,52,57],
           "De Vrie": [364,45,58,95,101,10,41,101,92,66,18,35,20,47,19,10,20,15,32,40,15,26,8,16,8,41,13,19,119,10,6,6,18,29,12,28,133,3,15,22],
           "inter": [299,85,26,34,29,15,18,38,27,16,18,9,8,13,17],
           "activisten": [161,44,139,155,25,53,58,61],
           "newdems": [78,77,52,35,59,20,21,6,11,8,11,23,7,28,32,19]}

election_result(parties, 7)
```

It prints how many seats each party is assigned according to the [D'Hondt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method):

```
020 - 1 seat(s)
De Vrie - 3 seat(s)
inter - 1 seat(s)
activisten - 1 seat(s)
newdems - 1 seat(s)
```

Function itself:

```
def election_results(parties: dict, seats: int) -> dict:

    """Looks cool"""

    assigned_seats = {p: sum(all_votes) // (sum([sum(all_votes) for all_votes in parties.values()]) // seats) for p, all_votes in parties.items()}
    while sum([seats_ for seats_ in assigned_seats.values()]) < seats:
        assigned_seats[[p for p in parties if (sum(parties[p]) // (assigned_seats[p] + 1)) == max([sum(all_votes) // (assigned_seats[p] + 1) for p, all_votes in parties.items()])][0]] += 1
    [print(f"\r{k} - {v} seat(s)") for k, v in assigned_seats.items()]
    return assigned_seats
```

P.S. Converting the `while` loop is definitely too much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: Here are the rules of thumb with list comprehensions:

- don't nest them
- don't use them for [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))
- don't use them if they require more than ~70 characters width, or have longwinded conditions
- don't use them to build a big list if you're just going to take one element
- don't use them if they in any way make the code harder to understand than a traditional loop--never try to be clever or write code because it "looks cool" (unless you're code golfing).

This code breaks all of the rules.

---

**Long answer**: Yes, this is definitely a misuse of list comprehensions. Frankly, it's an unreadable mess.

> Where is the line?

The line is the same as any code feature/tool: use it if it benefits the code in terms of some metric(s) (performance, readability, maintainability, etc) and don't use it if it doesn't. Software engineering is basically a long series of judgement calls like this, analyzing tradeoffs and picking the solution that makes the most sense for whatever goals you might have.

In almost any non-competitive, non-code golf context, the goals are speed of development versus maintainability, with performance occasionally an important factor. If all things seem equal, lean towards maintainability while keeping a reasonable pace and avoiding premature optimizations.

As a rule of thumb, lines should never be longer than 80 characters in any language. Putting your code into [Black](https://black.vercel.app/) gives immediate improvements in this regard:

```py
def election_results(parties: dict, seats: int) -> dict:
    """Looks cool"""
    assigned_seats = {
        p: sum(all_votes)
        // (sum([sum(all_votes) for all_votes in parties.values()]) // seats)
        for p, all_votes in parties.items()
    }
    while sum([seats_ for seats_ in assigned_seats.values()]) < seats:
        assigned_seats[
            [
                p
                for p in parties
                if (sum(parties[p]) // (assigned_seats[p] + 1))
                == max(
                    [
                        sum(all_votes) // (assigned_seats[p] + 1)
                        for p, all_votes in parties.items()
                    ]
                )
            ][0]
        ] += 1
    [print(f"\r{k} - {v} seat(s)") for k, v in assigned_seats.items()]
    return assigned_seats
```

A rule of thumb with list comprehensions is to avoid nesting them. This code would be a terrible chore to safely modify without introducing bugs. One would need to de-obfuscate the code just to figure out what it even does, much less go about modifying it. Nested list comprehensions often hide unnecessary repeated work.

Another rule of thumb with list comprehensions is to avoid using them for side effects, like printing. List comprehensions allocate memory, so using them to print involves expensive work that just gets thrown away to the garbage collector. Worse, it's not idiomatic and hides the intent of the code.

Functions that perform logic shouldn't print to begin with. They should silently return results and let the caller decide what to do.

`"""Looks cool"""` is pretty much an insult to the reader. Imagine there's a bug in the company's code and the developer that was hired to replace you has to deal with this function. I'd vouch they'll see it as extremely uncool. Be nice to that person because you may find yourself in the same position.

A good point is that you've added some type hints. However, the `dict` hint doesn't contain key and value types.

Another good point is that your variable names are generally pretty clear. But the inner list comprehensions have no names, so it's unclear what they represent. Intermediate variables and functions would de-anonymize them and make their purpose clear.

One list comprehension achieves nothing except a wasted allocation and loop:

```
while sum([seats_ for seats_ in assigned_seats.values()]) < seats:
```

can be

```
while sum(assigned_seats.values()) < seats:
```

Here's a first pass at a rewrite. I haven't looked at the algorithm, so there are probably other optimizations available. I didn't bother ensuring that I haven't broken something. If I did regress functionality, my point is proven.

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterable, List


Parties = Dict[str, List[int]]
Result = Dict[str, int]


def flatten(lst: Iterable) -> List:
    return [x for y in lst for x in y]


def sum_dict_values(dct: Dict[Any, List[int]]) -> int:
    return sum(flatten(dct.values()))


def find_best_party(parties: Parties, assigned_seats: Result) -> str:
    return max(parties, key=lambda p: sum(parties[p]) // (assigned_seats[p] + 1))


def determine_election_results(parties: Parties, seats: int) -> Result:
    total_votes = sum_dict_values(parties)
    assigned_seats = {
        p: sum(votes) // (total_votes // seats) for p, votes in parties.items()
    }

    while sum(assigned_seats.values()) < seats:
        best_party = find_best_party(parties, assigned_seats)
        assigned_seats[best_party] += 1

    return assigned_seats


def main():
    parties = {
        "020": [550, 198, 52, 57],
        "De Vrie": [364, 45, 58, 95, 101, 10, 41, 101, 92, 66, 18, 35, 20, 47, 19, 10, 20, 15, 32, 40, 15, 26, 8, 16, 8, 41, 13, 19, 119, 10, 6, 6, 18, 29, 12, 28, 133, 3, 15, 22],
        "inter": [299, 85, 26, 34, 29, 15, 18, 38, 27, 16, 18, 9, 8, 13, 17],
        "activisten": [161, 44, 139, 155, 25, 53, 58, 61],
        "newdems": [78, 77, 52, 35, 59, 20, 21, 6, 11, 8, 11, 23, 7, 28, 32, 19],
    }
    assigned_seats = determine_election_results(parties, 7)

    for k, v in assigned_seats.items():
        print(f"\r{k} - {v} seat(s)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```